# Pop-up with radiobuttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

I have a registration page where i have a register button and when it is clicked i have to get a pop up with radio buttons like parent and child.How to do this without javascript?I am using c# and asp.net.

```
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>


    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        Visible="False">
        <asp:ListItem>parent</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>child</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="RadioButtonList1_ModalPopupExtender"     runat="server"           PopupControlID="form1"
        DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="Button1">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>


</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Why is it that you want to avoid JavaScript?

Comment: Do you want a solution for which you dont need to write any javascript or something that will work when javascript is disabled?

Comment: I am using ajax modal popup extender but nothing iw working when i click the button.I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could just submit what the user has done so far, and direct to a different page with those radio buttons.
Or make a link to pop-up a new window to the radio buttons perhaps.
Or use css hoveron effect to mimic a popup block, thought this doesn't work like buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is using [JQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). I suggest you to give it a try.